# Best way to define a database with product codes and back-end support?

Tags: php, customization, database

**First let me explain what my wanted situation is:**

I have a WordPress site where I want the Admin to have access to about 10.000 "product keys". These codes will be inserted in a database of some sort (could be the original WP database, however I think a new db would be safer).

The user then must be able to go to a specified WP page in the front-end where he can insert the "product key" he got from the package of the item he bought.

The "product key" is then checked in the database for previous usage, and if not used before the user van use it to register his purchase. This registration must be done by filling out a couple of fields in the front-end (date of purchase, supplier, etc.) These fields must be updated in the row with the product key.

After this is done the admin must be able to search in the back-end for a product key, and can then view the information supplied by the user.

**Now my question is, how can I achieve this kind of behaviour in the most convenient way?** 
I have thought about "Custom Post types", but this feels wrong in this situation. I cannot seem to find the best option for this. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: feels like custom table architecture for this scenario is the best choice if you are not rolling it into a separate DB.

Comment: @BrandtSolovij So what you would suggest is building a plugin from scratch with connection to a table architecture from where I can add/update these values? Thanks!

Comment: -depending on goals yes. An inventory management system would be a significant extension of the WP Core intention - a plugin or purpose based theme would be the best route